# Javascript is not called from RequestContext in ManagedBean

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, primefaces

Well, i have a JS file with a lot of functions. In a specific case i can't call my method. See:

```html
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Montar" actionListener="#{orcamentoMB.montar}" />
</h:form>
```

And my actionListener is:

```
public void montar(){
    addInfoMessage("Chamando montagem de odontograma");
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("montarOdontograma()");
}
```

And my Javascript function:

```
function montarOdontograma() {
    alert('cool, this works');
}
```

A very simple example, but didn't work.

EDIT 1: My whole page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/templates/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Montar" actionListener="#{orcamentoMB.montar}" />
        <div id="container">
            <div id="supe"></div>
            <div id="supd"></div>

            <div id="mei1e"></div>

            <div id="mei1d"></div>

            <div id="mei2e"></div>

            <div id="mei2d"></div>

            <div id="infe"></div>

            <div id="infd"></div>
        </div>
        </h:form>       
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>


</h:body>
</html>
```

EDIT 2: Trying use onload to call javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body onload="montarOdontograma()">
    <ui:composition template="/templates/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form id="formManterOrcamento">

                <p:remoteCommand process="@this"
                    actionListener="#{orcamentoMB2.montarOdontograma}"
                    name="montarOdontograma" />
```

**SOLVED:**

The RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute() just work with ajax requests. In my case i just change the RequestContext to call directly with a  tag, see bellow:

```
<script>
  function init(){
    montarOdontograma();
  }

  window.onload = init;
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `execute("montarOdontograma()")`?

Comment: Yes, i already tried with "()".

Comment: Note that the example uses PrimeFaces CommandButton: `<p:commandButton>`, which fires an ajax request by default, contrary to `<h:commandButton>`. Try replacing it.

Comment: I already tried with primefaces too, but didn't work.

Comment: Please post the code of your whole page.

Comment: Ready, i posted my whole page.

Comment: I have to ask two things: 1) Is the Javascript function included in the template file */templates/template.xhtml*? 2) In the generated HTML code, is your `<form>` inside another `<form>`?

Comment: Unhappy what? Please post the code of your template as well.

Comment: Luggi i discovered something strange. When i use a commandButton to call a actionListener that call "RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute()" this works fine, but if i put RequestContext inside a method that is not called from a commandButton, didn't work. Is like the method must be a "actionListener" i don't know why.

Comment: Can I ask if this method that uses `RequestContext` is used inside a method fired by a client ajax request?

Comment: no Luiggi, ins't inside a ajax request.

Comment: Then it is working as expected. This `RequestContext` will just work inside ajax requests. Why did you expect it to work outside them?

Comment: See.. When my page is loaded i need call this Javascript method to build a draw in screen, i just puted the "alert()" in function in this post but this is much more complex.

Comment: Then you could use a `<p:remoteCommand>` to work as a JavaScript method, execute it in `window.onload()` JavaScript event and attach an `oncomplete` JavaScript method in the `<p:remoteCommand>` to be executed after the server side method was invoked.

Comment: Note that you would have better help and guidance if you post what you need to achieve and how you're trying to solve it.

Comment: I can't use onload from body tag because i'm using "<ui:define>" i need another technice to load just this in this specific page.

Comment: Yes you can. Did you at least tried it? Note that you can add JavaScript in your current page besides the JavaScript in the template...

Comment: yeah i tried but didn't work i will post the code.

Comment: It won't work like that. Just add this below `<ui:composition template"...">`: `<script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = function() { montarOdontograma(); }; </script> <!-- rest of your JSF code... -->`

Comment: Very good, it's works. Thanks for you patience Luiggi. You're my Hero.

Comment: You're welcome. I moved my comment into an answer. Please accept it if helped you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments, you just want to invoke a javascript function after window loading. Just define the `window.onload` function inside your `<ui:define>`:

```html
<h:body>
<ui:composition template="/templates/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                montarOdontograma();
                //more JavaScript code you want/need to execute...
            };
        </script>
        <h:form>
            <!-- rest of your JSF code... -->
</h:body>
```